# how to disable ckeditor 3 auto spellchecker?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've installed CKEditor 3.0 ,it work nice , but I want to disable the auto spellchecker
I notice when I'm writing some words in the editor it manages to connect to "svc.spellchecker.net"
to make spell check

do you know any way to stop that feature ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

The option that you want is [scayt_autoStartup](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.scayt_autoStartup)

Answer (score 11):

Better disable the plugin in config.js

config.removePlugins = 'scayt';

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I've used:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

// Disable spellchecker
config.scayt_autoStartup = false;

// Other configurations
config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

config.toolbar =
    [
         ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']
    ];
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font, maximize, resize, scayt';
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/boDocumentos';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/boDocumentos/upload';
config.filebrowserImageWindowWidth = '640';
config.filebrowserImageWindowHeight = '720';
```

};

Answer (score 1):

just set scayt_autoStartup = false;

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){

var CKEditor = $jq('textarea.ckEditor');

// CKEditor
CKEditor.ckeditor({
    //*
    disableNativeSpellChecker:true,
    scayt_autoStartup:false,
    toolbar:[
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Undo','Redo'], ....
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html) suggests that you set the `disableNativeSpellChecker` to true in CKEDITOR.config.

Comment: That option's default is `true` and disables the *browser's* spell check facilities - not CKEditor's `scayt`, which is generating the connections. If you disable `scayt`, you should set `disableNativeSpellChecker` to **false**.